# Writing multiple queries from a test file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filewriter

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> studentTokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> studentIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        // Open the file that is the first
        // command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File("file1.txt"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream, "UTF8"));

        String strLine;
        // Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            strLine = strLine.trim();

            if ((strLine.length()!=0) && (!strLine.contains("#"))) {
                String[] students = strLine.split("\\s+");
                studentTokens.add(students[TOKEN_COLUMN]);
                studentIds.add(students[STUDENT_ID_COLUMN]);
            }

        }





        for (int i=0; i<studentIds.size();i++) {
            File file = new File("query.txt");                                                      // The path of the textfile that will be converted to csv for upload
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = "", oldtext = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                                                                 
                oldtext += line + "\r\n";
            }
            reader.close();
            String newtext = oldtext.replace("sanid", studentIds.get(i)).replace("salabel",studentTokens.get(i));                                           // Here the name "sanket" will be replaced by the current time stamp 
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("final.txt",true);
            writer.write(newtext);
            writer.close();
        }


        fstream.close();
        br.close(); 
        System.out.println("Done!!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

The above code of mine reads data from a text file and query is a file that has a query in which 2 places "sanid" and "salabel" are replaced by the content of string array and writes another file final  . But when i run the code the the final does not have the queries. but while debugging it shows that all the values are replaced properly.

Comment: So `System.out.println(newtext)` prints the right data but `final.txt` does not contain the same thing?

Comment: use stringbuffer append method

Answer (score 0):

> but while debugging it shows that all the values are replaced properly

If the values are found to be replaced when you debugged the code, but they are missing in the file, I would suggest that you flush the output stream. You are closing the `FileWriter` without calling `flush()`. The `close()` method delegates its call to the underlying `StreamEncoder` which does not flush the stream either.

```
public void close() throws IOException {
se.close();
}
```

Try this

```
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

That should do it.